# Unarchiving NSMutableArray in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm adding objects to an NSMutableArray and archiving it with NSKeyedArchiver and UserDefaults.

Objects are added to the array, which I can see from the log console. I can also see that the archived objects contains the object.

***The problem is*** that I whenever I unarchive the objects and add them to the mutable array, it always returns 1, no matter how many object I add.

Here's what I got:

**Save objects to the array**

```
trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed.add(questionsArray[randomQuestion] as AnyObject)

let saveQuestionsPlayed = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed)
UserDefaults.standard.set(saveQuestionsPlayed, forKey: "QuestionsPlayed")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "QuestionsPlayed"))
```

**Retrieve the objects**

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "QuestionsPlayed") as? Data {

   if let trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSMutableArray)
    {
       // In here you can access your array
       print("Number of questions array is NOT empty: \(trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't store data in `UserDefaults`. Write to a file. 2. This is Swift. Don't use `NSMutableArray`. 3. Use `Codable`/`Decodable` and `PropertyListEncoder`/`PropertyListDecoder`. 4. No need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: Can you print trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed array and post the output?

Comment: This is a sample of what is stored in the trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed  array:

             (
                    {
                    A = Jefta;
                    Answer = A;
                    B = Jakob;
                    C = Adam;
                    Hint = "Dommerne 11:35";
                    Question = "Hvem aflagde et l\U00f8fte efter han vandt en stor sejr?";
                    Style = QUESTION;
                    URL = "http://wol.jw.org/da/wol/b/r9/lp-d/Rbi8/D/1993/7/11#h=130:199-131:0";
                },
            )

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm answering my own question. It turns out with a little bit tweaking you can save an array as described in my question. It turned out that some other code in my quiz game made a mess of it all. Sorted it out, and now the code below works:

**Save objects to the array**

```
 trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed.add(questionsArray[randomQuestion] as AnyObject)
            let saveQuestionsPlayed = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(saveQuestionsPlayed, forKey: "QuestionsPlayed")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            print("Count: \(trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed.count)")
```

**Retrieve the objects**

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "QuestionsPlayed") as? Data {

            if let trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSMutableArray)
            {
                // In here you can access your array
                self.trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed = trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed
                print("Number of questions array is NOT empty: \(trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed.count)")
            }
        } else {

            trackNumberOfQuestionPlayed = NSMutableArray()
            print("questionsplayed is empty")
        }
```